# Excel download in Internet Explorer without Dialog Box Prompt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsp, internet-explorer

I am trying to implement download excel functionality using javascript

```
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange;
    var j = 0;
    tab = document.getElementById('table'); // id of table

    for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, ""); //remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    } else //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}
```

It is working fine in chrome. But in Internet Explorer, a 'SaveAs' dialog box is appearing. Is there a way, file could be downloaded without opening the dialog box

Comment: Why tag Excel? This has nothing to do with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The Save As dialog box displayed by the IE browser and you cannot control it from your code.

In the older versions of the IE browser there was an option to disable the download prompt.

In the latest version of the IE browser this option was removed for the security purpose.

So now there is no way to disable this dialog.

You can also refer this thread to see the discussion on this topic.

[How can I disable the "open or save" prompt when I try to open a file with IE 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/how-can-i-disable-the-open-or-save-prompt-when-i/e490416d-7cb5-4661-9e9d-4881872ed29d)